# Фильтрация данных массива

Tags: php

Возникла проблема с фильтрацией данных в массиве.
Суть такова:
1. Пользователь GET-ом отправляет данные фильтрации

```
index.php?type=filter&date=06.12&time=17:30&name=&price=&count=&address=&comment=
```

2. Имеем массив

```
array (size=76)   

0 =>  
    array (size=8)  
       0 => string '06.2012' (length=7)   
      1 => string '17:59' (length=5)  
      2 => string 'Велик б' (length=13)  
      3 => string '150' (length=3)  
      4 => string '1' (length=1)  
      5 => string 'Киев' (length=8)  
      6 => string 'Доставка' (length=16)  
      7 => string '1471962977  
' (length=11)  
  1 =>   
    array (size=8)  
      0 => string '06.2011' (length=7)  
      1 => string '17:59' (length=5)  
      2 => string 'Велик б' (length=13)  
      3 => string '150' (length=3)  
      4 => string '1' (length=1)  
      5 => string 'Киев' (length=8)  
      6 => string 'Доставка' (length=16)  
      7 => string '1471962720  
' (length=11)  
  2 =>   
    array (size=8)  
      0 => string '06.2010' (length=7)  
      1 => string '17:59' (length=5)  
      2 => string 'Велик б' (length=13)  
      3 => string '150' (length=3)  
      4 => string '1' (length=1)  
      5 => string 'Киев' (length=8)  
      6 => string 'Доставка' (length=16)  
      7 => string '1471962116  
' (length=11)
```

3. Нужно фильтровать данные исходного массива и возвращать фильтрованный.
   Есть предположения что нужно перебрать все комбинации. Например, если дата сошлась, проверять с временем и т.д. Но этот вариант трудоемкий и запутанный. Как можно по другому сделать?

Comment: Уточните, какие именно правила фильтрации должны применяться?

Comment: Копайте в сторону filter_var_array

Comment: Если $_GET['data'] == $array[0][0] проверять по следующему полю, если нет проверять уже по второму. Возвращать массив совпадений

Comment: Можно вот такой адский вариант попробовать https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPHP

Comment: Под словом «фильтровать» вы имеете в виду исключить дубли? Или отсортировать по дате-времени?

Comment: Отфильтровать значит убрать с массива данные которые не попадают с фильт запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class Filter{
    private $out = array();

    public function __construct($input){
        $this->out = $input;
    }

    public function byField($field, $pattern){
        $temp = array();
        foreach ($this->out as $value){
            if(isMatch($value[$field], $pattern)){
                $temp[] = $value;
            }
        }
        $this->out = $temp;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getResult(){
        return $this->out;
    }

    private function isMatch($value, $pattern){
        #тут производите проверку, попадает ли под условия фильтра и возвращаете true или false
    }
}
```

использование

```
$myArray = array(.....);
$filter = new Filter($myArray);
$filtered = $filter
    ->byField('date', $_GET['date'])
    ->byField('time', $_GET['time'])
    ....
    ->byField('count', $_GET['count'])
    ->getResult;
```

Comment: А если нет значения в get пустой он вернет false

Comment: @MykolaShkit если бы я сюда закинул полностью рабочий класс под вашу конкретную задачу, то вышла бы изрядная простыня. Естественно никто не освобождает от контроля входных данных и прочих нюансов конкретно вашего случая.

Comment: @MykolaShkit Можно, например, в метод isMatch внести первой строкой if($pattern === null) return true; Вообще способов вагон и маленькая тележка

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень помогли только нужно еще добавить проверку пустой ли массив $temp